# Mootools variable scope issues

Tags: variables, scope, mootools

I have a problem getting my mind round variable scope and could do with some help :)

I'm setting up a module in joomla that will rotate images.  I've a bit of code I've used on non Joomla sites that works fine.  However I've ported it and I'm running into problems that I think are variable scope issues so any thoughts would be great.

Sorry for the long code but I included the whole function in case (when it works) it might help someone else.

```
function slideshow(container,containerCaption,previewCode,timer,classis,headerId,thumbOpacity,titlebar){
    var showDuration = timer;
    var container = $(container);
    var images = $(container).getElements('span');
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var interval;

    var preview = new Element('div',{
        id: containerCaption,
        styles: {
            opacity: thumbOpacity
        }
    }).inject(container);

    preview.set('html',previewCode);
    images.each(function(img,i){ 
    if(i > 0) {
        img.set('opacity',0);
    }
});

var show = function() {
    images[currentIndex].fade('out');
    images[currentIndex = currentIndex < images.length - 1 ? currentIndex+1 :         0].fade('in');

    var title = '';
    var captionText = '';

    if(images[currentIndex].get('alt')) {
        cap = images[currentIndex].get('alt').split('::');
        title = cap[0];
        captionText = cap[1];
        urltoUse = cap[2];
        preview.set('html','<span class="lctf1"><ahref="'+urltoUse+'">' 
            + title + '</a></span>' 
            + (captionText ? '<p>' + captionText + '</p>' : ''));
        }
    };

    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
        interval = show.periodical(showDuration);
    });
}

window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    container = "slideshow-container";
    containerCaption ="slideshow-container-caption";
    previewCode = '<span ><a href="<?php echo $itemurl[0];?>"><?php echo $itemtitle[0];?></a></span><p ><?php echo $itemdesc[0];?></p>';
    timer = <?php echo $slidetime*1000;?>;
    classis = 1;
    headerId = "";

    thumbOpacity =0.7;
    titlebar = "<?php echo $showTitle;?>";
    if($(container)){
        slideshow(container,containerCaption,previewCode,timer,classis,headerId,thumbOpacity,titlebar);
    }
});
```

The javascript error being thrown is that preview is undefined.

Comment: all your variables are define in private functions which the domready callback has no direct access to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work, I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7E2MX/3/ which runs with no errors.

I did change one line though:

```
var images = $(container).getElements('span');
```

to

```
var images = $(container).getElements('img');
```